# position a absolutely positioned div dynamically

Tags: css

At [this page](http://freightplus.com/beta/example2.html), from view port width 1024px and narrower, the #slider's absolute position stops working properly, because the logo's width becomes fluid:

[image]

```
.top_header-logo.grid12-8 img {
    width: 80%;
}
#slider {width: 90%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 184px; display:table-cell; background-color: #8A0E02; z-index: 9998;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #slider {top: 165px;}   
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #slider {top: 145px;}   
}
```

I'm looking for a solution to allow the #slider to be positioned at the top of `<div class="banner grid12-12">` (i.e. directly below the navigation menu, with no gap).

I could make `#slider` `position:relative;` but that would destroy the layout of the slider/sidebar combination.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Just to add to your woes, at screens larger than `2291px` your slider doesnt fill the full width of the screen, and instead starts creating a white "gap" on the right. [Image of issue](http://imgur.com/a/bCHNR)

Comment: Okay, thanks @haxxxton.